# installing ruby 2.0.0 rvm osx 10.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rvm, osx-snow-leopard, ruby-2.0

I'm having a bit of a problem upgrading Ruby to 2.0.0 and Rails to 3.2.13.  I was using [this guide](http://railsapps.github.com/updating-rails.html), and got to the step to create a new project specific gem list for ruby 2.0.0 and rails 3.2.13.

here's the [code](http://txtup.co/Z8TTy)

and the files:

/usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/yaml/configure.log:
`http://txtup.co/f7taC`
/usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/openssl/configure.log:
`http://txtup.co/vmXHM`
/usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/yaml/make.log:
`http://txtup.co/wIowb`
/usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/openssl/make.log:
`This is massive. I'll upload it if you ask me to`
/usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/configure.log:
`http://txtup.co/zbNiz`

If there's anything else you need, let me know.  Not sure what I've done, but not really sure what to do next.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
rvm get head
rvm install 2.0.0 --autolibs=4
```

Comment: first command: http://txtup.co/jIYz  
  
second command: http://txtup.co/YYEiZ
  
/usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/brew_install.log: http://txtup.co/ZlYlx

Comment: that should work in bash, please open [rvm ticket](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues) to fix it in ZSH